# Lobster Challenge: zsh: no matches found error on building transaction

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

So I'm trying to build the transaction for voting on the naming of Charles Lobster. However whenever i specify the UTXO as TxHash + "#" + TxIx it complains and says

`zsh: no matches found: TxHash#TxIx`

But then whenever i take out the #TxIx part and leave it as TxHash it complains and says

`option --tx-in: unexpected end of input expecting hexadecimal digit or "#"`

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. It's my first time with the cardano node so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. For anyone facing the same issue you need to escape the # key by putting a backslash before it like so:

`TxHash\#TxIx`